the y coordinate is missing in new Vector2, although I have configured it for use in unity
I have a new Vector2(pos1) and for some reason it writes to me that there is no y
p.s. my code is huge, so I tore out of it what really concerns the problem
private bool trigger = false;
public int SceneIndex;
public GameObject Black;
public GameObject Hero;
public bool shouldTeleport;
Vector2 pos1 = new Vector2(0, 0);

private void Update()
{
    if (trigger && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        StartCoroutine(BlackScreenCoroutine());
    }
}

private IEnumerator BlackScreenCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        GameObject blackObject = Instantiate(Black);
        blackObject.SetActive(true);
        blackObject.transform.localScale = newVector2(100f, 100f);
        Hero.transform.position = new Vector2(pos1);

        // Запуск новой корутины
        StartCoroutine(heroCoroutine());
    }
}


What do you mean "it writes to you" that there is no y?
What is "Hero"? What is "Black"?
Your code segment is poorly formatted. Please translate your comments into english or leave them out of your post.

Unitys Vector2 expects two parameters in the constructor, you are passing only one pos1. You should write new Vector2(pos1.x, pos1.y).
Source: Unitys Documentation

What you really want to call here is new Vector3(pos1.x pos1.y), because you are assigning it to Vector3 when passing it to transform.position.

Unity has implicit type conversion operators between Vector2 and Vector3. So assigning a Vector2 to a Vector3 value does actually work. Though "z" will be implicitly set to 0 which you should never assign as a scale.

The Vector2 struct does not have a constructor that takes another Vector2. It only accepts two float values.
Since Vector2 is a struct, there's no point in calling the constructor like that anyways since value types are always copied when passed around (unless it's a ref or out parameter).
So this line should probably be just
Hero.transform.position = pos1;

Note that this part would not compile as well

blackObject.transform.localScale = newVector2(100f, 100f);

as you're missing a space between new and Vector2.
